# If $f(x)=\sin(x)$, when $x$ is rational and $f(x)=\cos(x)$, when $x$ is irrational, will it be continuous at $x=n \pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Here $n$ is any integer. This is my attempt at solving the question:

Since $n \pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$ is irational, $f(x)=\cos(x)$. Let $h$ be a infinitesimally small positive quantity and $n=1$
$$
RHL=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+h\right)$$
$$LHL=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-h\right)$$

This is where my confusion begins, if we assume $h$ to be an infinitesimally small irrational number in the first case and infinitesimally small rational number in the second case then the function will be discontinuous.

If we assume $h$ to be an infinitesimally small rational number in the first case and infinitesimally small rational number in the second case then the function will be continuous.

However If we assume $h$ to be an infinitesimally small irrational number in the first case and infinitesimally small irrational number in the second case then the function will be discontinuous. So how can a function like this exist, and where am I going wrong?

Comment: $n\pi +\frac \pi 4$ is rational?  How's that?

Comment: Hint: angle-addition.

Comment: There are no infinitesimally small real numbers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh does this mean that there are certain limitations on the RHL,LHL method, i.e are there any functions like this where this method can't be used?

Comment: No there is no limitation to the lhl/rhl method. My objection is related to the notion of infinitesimals as used in your question. There is a way to learn / develop calculus using infinitesimals, but a majority of courses and textbooks don't use it. So the more popular version is the one without any infinitesimals.

Comment: In your approach both left and right limit equal $1/\sqrt{2}$ and $f(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$ so the function is continuous at $\pi/4$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh "In your approach both rho and lhl equal $1/ \sqrt2 $ are you finding the LHL and RHL directly by approximating h as 0 and substituting $\pi /4$ in the function or are you using some other rules of infinitesimals. If you are using the first method, wouldn't that make f(x) continuous at all points, which really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't use infinitesimals. There is no difference between lhl and rhl here. Depending on whether $(\pi/4)+h$ is rational or irrational the limit should equal $\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(\pi/4+h)$ or $\lim_{h\to 0}\cos(\pi/4+h)$ and both these are equal as $\cos\pi/4=\sin\pi/4$. Same happens with left hand limit (replace $h$ with $-h$). The function will be continuous at only those points $c$ where $\cos c=\sin c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the point $n\pi+(\pi/4)$ under consideration, say $a$, is irrational we have $f(a) =\cos a$ and thus $$|f(x) - f(a) |=|\sin x - \cos a|=|\sin x - \sin a|$$ as $\cos a =\sin a$ when  $x$ is rational and $$|f(x) - f(a) |=|\cos x-\cos a|$$ if $x$ is irrational.

Now observe that both the differences $|\sin x-\sin a|$ and $|\cos x - \cos a|$ never exceed $|x-a|$. Why??

Well, $$|\sin x - \sin a|=|2\cos((x+a)/2)\sin((x-a)/2)|\leq 2|(x-a)/2|=|x-a|$$ and similarly one can handle the other difference.

Hence $$0\leq |f(x) - f(a) |\leq |x-a|$$ If you are aware of definition of limit then the above inequality allows you to take $\delta =\epsilon $ and show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =f(a) $.

On the other hand if you are not aware of definition of limit you can use Squeeze theorem to conclude $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =f(a) $. And therefore the function is continuous at all points $a$ of the form $a=n\pi+(\pi/4)$.

Comment: How did you get the inequality $|2cos((x+a)/2)sin((x-a)/2)|<(x-a)$

Comment: @Sunaina: remember that both $\sin, \cos$ don't exceed $1$ in absolute value and hence we can get rid of $\cos ((x+a) /2)$. The expression is thus $\leq 2|\sin((x-a)/2)|$. Next use the fundamental inequality of $\sin x$ namely $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ for all real $x$ (this does not hold for $\cos $). Hence we get the expression $\leq 2|(x-a)/2|=|x-a|$.

Comment: @Sunaina: you should remember the basic inequalities satisfied by common functions. They are quite useful in calculus. For example $\log x\leq x - 1$ for all positive $x$ and $e^x\geq 1+x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Is continuity a requirement for the squeeze theorem to be applied, or does the successful application of squeeze theorem show that the function is continuous. I.e is finding a limit using squeeze theorem enough to prove the function is continuous?

Comment: @Sunaina: squeeze theorem is a tool to find limits in certain situations. It has nothing to do with continuity. Applying squeeze theorem in my answer gives you $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x) - f(a) |=0$ and this implies $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x) - f(a)) =0 $ and this implies $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =f(a) $ which finally means (by definition) that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = n \pi + \frac{\pi}4$. Note that
$$\sin x_n = \cos x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt 2} = f( x_n).\tag{1}\label{1}$$
So, intuitively, if you get close enough to $ x_n$ the function will approach the value $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt 2}$.

More formally, fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\sin x$ is continuous in in $x_n$, there exists $\delta_1$ such that
$$\left|\sin x - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt 2}\right| < \varepsilon$$
for all $x$ such that $|x - x_n| < \delta_1$.
Similarly, by continuity of $\cos x$ in $x_n$, there exists $\delta_2$ such that
$$\left|\cos x - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt 2}\right|< \varepsilon$$
for all $x$ such that $|x - x_n| < \delta_2$.

Now choose $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ and you get
$$\left| f(x) - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt 2}\right| < \varepsilon$$
for every $x$ that satisfies
$$|x-x_n| < \delta,$$
which implies, together with \eqref{1}, continuity of $f$ in $x_n$.

Comment: Thank you but I have some questions. What does $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ mean here? What do you mean by fixing the value?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of limit? E.g. https://brilliant.org/wiki/epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit/

Comment: so can we say directly for any function l(x) which is f(x) at some points at p(x) and other points that if both f(x) and p(x) are continuous and converge at a point x, l(x) will also be continuous at x?

Comment: @Sunaina yes you can say that